# How to add a new Kafka brokers machines dynamically to a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

We have Kafka confluent cluster , cluster include **3** Kafka brokers ,

Version details:

```
Kafka machines are installed on rhel version 7.2 
Kafka confluent version is 0.1x
Zookeeper version: 3.4.10
schema-registry version: 4.0.0
```

Each Kafka broker machine include the following services

```
Kafka broker
Zookeeper server
Schema registry
```

Now we want to add a additionally new `3 Kafka` brokers machines to the current Kafka cluster ( the Additional Kafka machines are – `kafka04/05/06` with the same Kafka version – `0.1X` , )

So cluster should be finally with:

`6 Kafka` brokers machines - `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03 , kafka04 , kakfa05 , kafka05`

`3 zookeeper` servers - `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03`

`3 schema registry` services - `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03`

In order to connect the new `3 Kafka` brokers to the existing Kafka cluster we need to change the Configuration on all Kafka Machines ( the old Kafka machines and the new Kafka machines )

We are not sure what are exactly the configuration files in Kafka brokers that should be changed,  But From my ***understanding*** We should change the Kafka and zookeeper settings as the following

***I will happy to get remarks/notes about the following procedure***

1. Edit the `server.properties` file on the new Kafka brokers - `kafka04/05/06` ,  and change the   `broker.id` parameter as the following

   On kafka04 - `broker.id=4`
   On kafka05 - `broker.id=5`
   On kafka06 - `broker.id=6`
2. Edit the server.properties on all Kafka machines - `kafka01/02/03/04/05/06`
   And change the following parameters to the number of total nodes in the cluster

   ```
    offsets.topic.replication.factor=6
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor=6
   ```
3. On the new Kafka machines - `Kafka 04/05/06`  edit the  `server.properties`  and update the parameter -- `zookeeper.connect` with the  zookeeper server ip’s that located on `kafka01` , `kafka02` , `kafka03`

   Example

   ```
    zookeeper.connect=10.10.10.1:2181,10.10.10.2:2181,10.10.10.3:2181
   ```
4. On Kafka machines – `kafka 04/05/06` , edit the file - `zookeeper.properties` as the
   Following

   ```
   server.1=10.10.10.1:2888:3888
   server.2=10.10.10.2:2888:3888
   server.3=10.10.10.3:2888:3888
   ```
5. Edit the file -  `myid` file on `Kafka 04/05/06` , and change the parameter `broker.id` as the
   Following

   on `kafka04` set:

   ```
    broker.id=4
   ```

   on `kafka05` set:

   ```
    broker.id=5
   ```

   on `kafka06` set:

   ```
    broker.id=6
   ```
6. After settings as above , restart all Kafka brokers services on `kafka01/02/03/04/05/06` and Restart the zookeeper servers on `kafka01/02/03`

   And verify all Kafka services and zookeeper service started successfully

Reference info - https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/current/PlatformAnalytics/en-us/Content/Add_kafka_node_to_kafka_cluster.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When adding brokers, you don't need to change the configuration of existing brokers, nor restart them. The same applies to ZooKeeper, if you are not adding new ZooKeeper servers.

On the new brokers, you just need to set a different `broker.id` value.

I don't recommend increasing the replication factor of the topics (including internal) beyond 3.

Once your new brokers are started, you may want to rebalance your existing data. There are many tools to do that, including the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool. The Kafka docs has a section detailing the process: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

Comment: but what about the zookeeper.properties on the kafka machines kafka01-kafka06?

Comment: I update my question regarding to   zookeeper.properties , is it ok?

Comment: If you don't run ZooKeeper on these new machines, you don't need to touch `zookeeper.properties`.

Comment: so I need to copy the zookeeper.properties from kafka01 to new kafka machines?

Comment: If you don't run ZooKeeper on these new machines you don't even need the `zookeeper.properties` file there! This file is only necessary to run ZooKeeper on a machine.